# Is Hbase schema on read?

Tags: hadoop, schema, hbase

I am new to hbase . I know that HBase is key/value store which stores the data in array of bytes. couple of queries

1. Does Hbase support data types for columns ?
2. Is Hbase schema on read (like hive ) or write ?

For the first question , I saw couple of links and got confused.

---

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.analyze.doc/doc/bsql_encoding.html

[Java(HBase) API: How to know the data type of a value stored in bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834372/javahbase-api-how-to-know-the-data-type-of-a-value-stored-in-bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Natively HBase does not support data types for columns everything is treated as byte arrays. Here is an excert from hbase book on [supported data types](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/supported.datatypes.html). But you could use high level frameworks like [phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/) and here are its [supported data types](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html).
2. As HBase is schema-less I would say HBase relies on schema on read mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Ashrith. I understand better now . so the explanation on above IBM link, where they are mentioning the data types for columns in HBase create table , is it something specific to their product ?

CREATE HBASE TABLE enc_bin
(
   ti TINYINT, si SMALLINT, i INT,
   bi BIGINT, b BOOLEAN, f FLOAT,
   d DOUBLE, s1 STRING, s2 STRING,
   s3 STRING, s4 STRING, s5 STRING
) 
COLUMN MAPPING(
  KEY  MAPPED BY (s1,ti,bi,i) ENCODING BINARY,
  f1:a MAPPED BY (si,s2,f) ENCODING BINARY,
  f1:b MAPPED BY (d,b,s3) ENCODING BINARY,
  f1:c MAPPED BY (s4,s5) ENCODING BINARY
)
;

Comment: Yes, looks like its specific to IBM biginsights, it looks similar to what Phoenix provides. Any how the way they do it is using coprocessors to intercept the schema. But natively HBase does not support something like that.